# Mavericks - APN Active Directory Users not being pushed

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

We have hit a problem with our current AD -> OSX Server integration project.

We have our OSX server (mavericks) connected to our AD domain and running open directory/profile manager.

AD users can sign in to OSX clients (mavericks) using their AD credentials (and their home directories are mounting via SMB).

The OSX clients (mavericks) are enrolled and receive profile push notifications successfully for both device and device group profile updates.

They do not however receive push notifications when changes are made to the user profile (even when the device is associated with the user within profile manager).

We see the communication going out to APN from the server but we don't see the inbound push from APN to the device (like we do for device and group level profile updates).

Any thoughts on why we might be experiencing this behavior?